# Sharper approximation for $\sum_{k=1}^n (2k - 1)^\alpha$ for $\alpha > 0$?

Tags: inequality, approximation, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the summation
$$S_n(\alpha) := \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^\alpha, \quad\mbox{where}~\alpha > 0. 
$$
By integration, it is possible to verify that
$$
\frac{2(\alpha + 1) + (2n - 1)^{\alpha + 1} - 1}{2(\alpha + 1)}\leq S_n(\alpha)\leq  \frac{(2n + 1)^{\alpha + 1} - 1}{2(\alpha + 1)}
$$
However, these bounds are not very accurate. In particular, if we
look at the ratio of the bounds,
$$
\sup_{n \geq 1} 
\frac{(2n + 1)^{\alpha + 1} - 1}{2(\alpha + 1) + (2n - 1)^{\alpha + 1} - 1} 
\geq \frac{3^{\alpha + 1} - 1}{2(\alpha + 1) - 1} \to \infty, \quad 
\mbox{as}~\alpha \to \infty. 
$$
So the ratio of these bounds for small $n$ blows up as the exponent increases.
Is it possible to have sharper bounds? In particular, it would be nice to have
approximations
$$
L_n(\alpha) \leq S_n(\alpha) \leq U_n(\alpha), 
\quad\mbox{such that}\quad 
\sup_{\alpha > 0} \sup_{n \geq 1} \frac{U_n(\alpha)}{L_n(\alpha)} < \infty.
$$
Of course this is possible by taking $U_n = L_n = S_n$, but the goal would be to have some `simpler' $U_n, L_n$.

Comment: I don't understand your calculation. That sup calculation concerns the case $n = 1$: if you're interested in that case, or more generally in the case that $n$ remains small but $\alpha \to \infty$, then what do you need bounds for? For fixed $n$ it's completely clear how the sum behaves as $\alpha \to \infty$. Is that the asymptotic regime you're interested in?

Comment: In any case, if the asymptotic regime you're actually interested in is $\alpha$ fixed but $n \to \infty$, or more generally $\alpha, n \to \infty$ but $\alpha$ growing somewhat slowly compared to $n$ (I don't know how much more slowly will suffice), the tool you want is the Euler-Maclaurin formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: I am a bit confused. I have stated a precise way in which I would like bounds. I have asked for a bound which is sharp in the sense that the ratio $U_n(\alpha)/L_n(\alpha)$ is bounded for all $n, \alpha$. Is that not possible for some reason?

Comment: The problem here imho is this notion of "simpler" since $S_n(\alpha)$ has different behaviours in different asymptotic regimes (eg it is a polynomial if $\alpha$ is much smaller than $n$, an exponential if $\alpha$ is much bigger than $n$ and superexponential if $\alpha$ is the size of $n$ just to mention three simple asymptotic regimes so having $U/L$ bounded in each of the above three simple cases requires different kinds of  "simple expressions"

Comment: Yes, that exactly. The behavior is quite different in the asymptotic regime where $n$ is large compared to $\alpha$ vs. vice versa. There's no reason to expect "simple" bounds which work uniformly in both regimes (or other regimes as Conrad discusses). Which one do you actually care about?

Comment: For example, your original expressions are good when $n$ is not much smaller than $\alpha$ (or of course is bigger) so $e^{\alpha/n}/\alpha$ is bounded so for example when $n >> \alpha/\log \alpha$; but when $n$ is say the size of $\sqrt \alpha$ you would need very tight bounds in $n$ so the expressions $f(n)^{\alpha} \le S_n(\alpha) \le g(n)^{\alpha}$ would need $g(n)/f(n)$ about $1+1/n^2$ rather than $1+1/n$ and of course that doesn't work if $n$ is of order $\log \alpha$ etc